# Truncated output from php in a webpage

Tags: php, python, html

I want to get the list of trams coming by my house. I have a python script that takes the times and spits them out. On every line there is the tram number , the next one is then on a new line.

```
$ /var/www/html/kvvliveapi.py departures de:8212:31
sofort  S1 Bad Herrenalb||||

1 min   3 Heide||||

1 min   3 Tivoli über Hbf||||

3 min   S2 Spöck||||

3 min   2 Wolfartsweier||||
```

I want to have this in a web page, so I run the script with php.

(in index.html)

```
<?php 
exec('python /var/www/html/kvvliveapi.py departures de:8212:31', $out);
echo implode("\n", $out);
?>
```

But then on the webpage it looks really weird. It doesn't have all the lines it has, when I run it in the terminal, and although I have new lines, on the web page everything is on one line.

```
sofort S1 Bad Herrenalb|||| 1 min 3 Heide||||
```

Comment: can you share the output of `print_r($out);`?

Comment: `Array
(
    [0] => 1 min   3 Heide
    [1] => 1 min   S2 Reitschulschlag
 
)`

Comment: Please check my post hope it will work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This same worked for me

**Solution 1:**

**Change this to**

```
echo implode("\n", $out);
```

**This:**

```
print_r(implode("<br>",$out));
```

**Solution2:**

**Change this to:**

```
echo implode("\n", $out);
```

**This:**

```
echo "<pre>";
echo implode("\n", $out);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: @ewcz I have done it practically still not working with just `echo $out` because `$out` is coming out to be array. Please refer http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php